# How do games have low tick rates without causing input lag?

Tags: networking, input, client-server, fixed-timestep

For example, Minecraft. It updates the gamestate at a rate of only 20/second. And from what I've read, these multiplayer games do the same with their network communication, sending updates at that same speed. So it sounds like the entire game is, internally, running very slow (ignoring the render interpolation to not appear slow).

But what I don't understand is how player input doesn't feel laggy as a result. If player input was only being sampled 20/second, you would feel the delay. But that isn't the case in Minecraft, it is extremely responsive. I assume that means player input is being sampled as fast as possible, at renderer speed. But that means the game is gathering input way faster than it can use it. If it updates the gamestate and talks to the server 20 times in a second, but gathers 200 input samples in that same time, how does it handle that?

Is it perhaps just faking it locally, taking the latest player input and interpolating the renderer with it to appear responsive, even though that input isn't actually being used anywhere in the game?

How does it decide which particular input sample to use when it's comes time to do a gamestate/network update without losing information?

I don't understand how to resolve the conflict between having too many input samples to use, and having input feel too slow.

Comment: Prediction. Read up on how Quake 3 did it back in the days of 56k dialup modems.

Comment: In Diablo III, the attack animation is started as soon as the player hits the button, but it's only visual sugar seen locally. It allows the packet to go to the server, the server to validate and process the attack and to send the packet back to the client, at which point the visuals of the actual attack is ready to happen.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this question. Everyone just says stuff like "it's obvious" "it's easy" "just predict stuff" etc. without answering the question. The closest thing I've found to a solution is this [Valve article](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Latency_Compensating_Methods_in_Client/Server_In-game_Protocol_Design_and_Optimization), which shows usercmd having an "msec" field which stores the client's frame time for the frame that input was sampled from. This would presumably allow you to re-simulate all inputs server-side accurately, but preventing abuse still seems difficult.

Comment: @Dan The best I've come up with is to have the server queue all player inputs. So the client (input and renderer) may be running at 60fps, while the server is running at 20fps. So when the server does an update, it'll have multiple input events from the client for that timespan. All it has to do is apply them, one after the other, to catch up.

Comment: @Nairou Yeah the problem with that approach is that the client can just send 50 input packets in 1 frame and "speed hack". I implemented something yesterday to try to prevent this where I put frameDt in the input packets then on the server side keep an accumulator and detect if a client has sent quite a bit more time worth of inputs than the simulation has actually stepped. This works surprisingly well except when the client has low FPS or stalls for some reason, in which case it's a false positive, but even in that case it probably makes sense to kick them anyway.